# Spring Security (3.0.5), different behavior in production (SSL) - ( ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: spring, spring-security, https

My Spring-login has been working from day 1 (since 2013) , it now only works on my local machine (localhost:8080) but not on the production-site (https). So the only thing that has been changed is that I have a new domain (https://naturforskaren.se/) instead of (https://dina-web.net/naturalist)

in production I either get his error (**chrome**) https://<url-to-site>/loginsuccess:

```
This page isn’t working <url-to-site> redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

or I get this error (**firefox**)  https://<url-to-site>/loginsuccess:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly
An error occurred during a connection to  https://<url-to-site>/loginsuccess
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

on Internet Explorer I get the following: https://<url-to-site>/loginsuccesss

```
make sure you've got the right web address: <url-to-site>
```

THis is my code:

(0) this is a part of the spring-security.xml file:

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/denied" >
        
    <!--<intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>-->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"   />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginsuccess" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" requires-channel="http" />
                
        <security:form-login
            login-page="/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
            default-target-url="/loginsuccess"/>
            
        <security:logout 
            invalidate-session="true" 
            logout-success-url="/logut" 
            logout-url="/logut"/>
    
    </security:http>
```

(1) The form (login.jps)

```
<form name='my_form' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="j_username"><fmt:message key="login.username" /></label>  
           <input style="margin-bottom: 10px" type='text' name='j_username' value='' class="form-control" placeholder="<fmt:message key="login.username_message" />" />
        <label for="j_password"><fmt:message key="login.password" /></label>  
          <input type='password' class="form-control" name='j_password' placeholder="<fmt:message key="login.password_message" />" />
       </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><fmt:message key="submit" /></button>
</form>
```

**A selection from the LoginFormController looks like this**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/loginsuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginSuccess(ModelMap model, Principal principal) throws Exception {
        String redirectTo = "redirect:/";
        HttpSession session = super.getSession();

        Map<String, Object> searchMap = new HashMap<>();
        searchMap.put("username", principal.getName());

        User user = (User) genericService.findByNamedQuery("User.findByUsername", searchMap);
        if (user == null) {
            String prefixError = "user not found in database ";
            logger.info(prefixError);
            session.setAttribute("exception", prefixError);
            redirectTo = redirectTo.concat("error/");
            // return redirectTo;
        } else {

            session.setAttribute("loginUser", user);

            final String preferredLanguage = user.getPreferredLanguage();
            session.setAttribute("lang", preferredLanguage);
            setUser(user);

            logger.info("Admin-Login: success :   " + getUser().getUsername() + " (lang : " + preferredLanguage + ")");

            Taxon taxon = (Taxon) session.getAttribute("currentTaxon");
            if (taxon != null) {
                redirectTo = redirectTo.concat("species/" + taxon.getUuid());
            }
        }
```

So in production: I get the /loginsuccess
I do get the log in genericService from this statement :
`User user = (User) genericService.findByNamedQuery("User.findByUsername", searchMap);`

so the user is correct and the login is ok.
I am not getting the the log from this statement
`logger.info("Admin-Login: success :   " + getUser().getUsername() + " (lang : " + preferredLanguage + ")");`

So, why am I now running into this error?

I have not changed any Spring versions , it is and has always been the following:

```
<spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<springsecurity.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
```

best, i

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the spring-security.xml-file:
change from 'https' to 'http'

Before:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"   />
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="https" /> 
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginsuccess" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https" />
```

and after:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"   />
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="http" /> 
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginsuccess" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="http" />
```